# Disable Keep-Alive in Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I need to be able to disable the Keep-Alive on my application using Kestrel, but I only found how to set the Keep-Alive timeout here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.keepalivetimeout?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Is it even possible to disable completely the keep-alive on kestrel ? and how to do so.

Thanks!

Comment: That's a strange request. This will seriously harm performance by requiring a new TCP connection for each request, in the same conversation. Why do you want to do that? In any case,  the `Keep-Alive` duration is [requested by the client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) Kestrel sets a limit to what the client can ask

Comment: I know it is a bad idea to disable the keep-alive but my customer requested it because of their in house proxy that can be "unstable with keep-alive". For the time being I asked them if a timeout of 1 ticks is an acceptable response for them, hopping they say yes.

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/1913). Perhaps you can set the `Connection: Close`  header ?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needed answer, setting the value to `TimeSpan.MaxValue` will disable it. More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29946788)